# How does Mathematica draw 2D and 3D graphics?

Tags: graphics, graphics3d, implementation-details, rendering

I'd like to know Mathematica draws **3D** graphics with respect to platform it's running on?

For Windows:

- Is it using Diret3D(DirectX)?

For Linux/Solaris:

- Is it Using OpenGL or Vulkan?

For Mac OS X:

- Is it using OpenGL or Metal?

If none of the above is being used then which mechanism is being used achieve 3D graphics ?

Thank you.

Comment: I think this page, particularly under the Details section, gives some indirect hints as to what is used: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RenderingOptions.html

Comment: @user6014 thank you dear friend.. I will search and get to know about it.. thank your for the link once again.

Comment: in good old days, in old versions, I think Mathematica graphics were all postscript.